# Why would a SQL query take significantly longer to run when the row return limit is increased by 1?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

When running the following query:

```
SELECT customers.ID, customers.FNAME, customers.MNAME, customers.LNAME,
    customers.SUFFIX, addresses.ADDRESS, addresses.CITY, addresses.STATE, 
    addresses.ZIP 
from db_name.customers 
INNER JOIN db_name.addresses ON customers.ID=addresses.CID
limit 6607;
```

while connected to a MariaDB instance on AWS RDS from MySQL workbench, the query runs with the following metadata results:

*6607 row(s) returned   Duration: 0.507 sec / Fetch Time: 8.524 sec*

Additionally, when the results are exported to a csv file, the size is about 466KB. However, when I run the same query with only changing the last line to retrieve one more row:
`limit 6608`
The query does not finish (I killed it after nearly an hour).

Furthermore, I noticed that the Fetch Time experiences a big jump between `limit 4000` and `limit 4001` rows.
Whether this insight useful or not, I have included a graph of fetch times (fetch time on the vertical axis) while varying the row limit (number of rows returned on the horizontal axis). I do not understand why fetch time appears to be a *piecewise* continuous (linear) function of rows returned:

Fetch time by row limit scatter plot
[image]

**If anyone has an idea about what is preventing me from returning more than 6607 rows, I would love your advice.** Thank you!

Comment: Looks like 4000 rows fill up a buffer, any more seem to cause another buffer to be sent from server to client, hence the jump in Fetch Time

Comment: a) Check available disk space. b) what happens when you add an offset (e.g. `limit 100 offset 6600` or `limit 6607 offset 1000`).

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok that makes sense. Do you think that the breakdown of the query after 6607 rows is a related problem? Any ideas on how more than 6607 rows may be returned? Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, LIMIT without ORDER BY. Is fairly meaningless

Comment: @Solarflare I tried your suggestions. ```limit 100 offset 6600``` had a fetch time of 0.0001 sec, but the query duration (as reported by workbench) was 3592.829 sec (about 1 hour). On the other hand, ```limit 6607 offset 10``` had a duration of 0.361 sec (in line with previous tests) but the fetch never completed (I killed it after several hours). I don't know what to make of this.

Comment: How many rows in the table?  What does the `EXPLAIN` say in each of the 3 LIMIT ranges?  Does AWS brag about their improvements in LIMIT handling?

Comment: (Nitpick:  I don't think that is called a "scatter plot".  The y-axis is 'dependent', not 'independent'.)

Comment: And which version of MariaDB?  (I'll check the changelogs in that area.)